# Why is this set needed in this proof?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

The theorem states that if $\{ f_n\}$ is a sequence of complex measurable functions defined almost everywhere on a set $X$ such that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{X}\vert f_n\vert\,\,d\mu<\infty\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$Then the series $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)$$converges for almost all $x$, $f$ is a Lebesgue integrable function, and $$\int_X f\,\,d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_X f_n(x)\,\,d\mu\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(3)$$
Note: $\mu$ is a measure

The proof states:
Let $S_n$ be the set on which $f_n$ is defined, so that $\mu(S^c_n)=0$. Put $\varphi(x)=\sum\vert f_n(x)\vert$ for $x\in S=\cap S_n$. Then $\mu(S^c)=0$. Then by equation $(1)$ $$\int_S \varphi d\mu<\infty$$ If $E=\{x\in S:\varphi(x)<\infty\}$, it follows from $(4)$ that $\mu(E^c)=0$.

My question:
I don't understand as to why $E$ is needed. Isn't $E=S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $E \subseteq S$ but $E \neq S$ in general. The point is that all your functions are defined up to almost everywhere conditions, so on a set of measure zero you might have some issues ; for instance, setting $f_n(x) = 1$ for some fixed $x \in S$ gives you $\varphi(x) = \infty$ for this value of $x$, which means $x \in S \backslash E$. However, the finiteness of $\int_S \varphi$ ensures $\mu(S\backslash E) = 0$ since $\varphi$ is positive.

Hope that helps,

Comment: But doesn't the fact that the Lebesgue integral $\int_S \varphi<\infty$ ensure that $\varphi (x)<\infty$ for any $x$?

Comment: @user97554 : That is precisely my point ; you can change the value of a function on a set of points of measure zero without changing the value of the integral.

Comment: @user97554 The Lebesgue integral $\int_S \psi < \infty$ implies that $\mu(\{x : \psi(x) =\infty\}) = 0$, it does not imply $\psi(x) < \infty$ for each $x$.